# It is not inserting any data into my mysql db..... I have inserted fillable field in my model user also

Tags: php, laravel-5

protected function create(array $data)
   {   $request = request();

```
    $profileImage = $request->file('image');
    $profileImageSaveAsName = time(). "." . $profileImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $profileImage->move('img', $profileImageSaveAsName);

    $user=new User;
    return $user->create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'image' => $profileImageSaveAsName,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Are you image data getting `$request->file('image')?` ie `enctype="multipart/form-data"` you added enctype to your `<form>` element right?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`.

---

Also, you are a bit overcomplicating things while saving image. (In fact I believe you should store into `storage/app/public/images` rather than `public/images`)

```
$profileImage = $request->file('image');
$fileName = time() . Auth::id() . "-profile." . $profileImage->getClientOriginalExtension();

$path = $profileImage->storeAs('public/images', $fileName);
```

For this to work, make sure you run the symlink command: `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 0):

first check you add in form `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`

and second, you cannot get `Auth::id()`,

because the user is not registered, Hence no session is created then how can you get id from Auth.
you can also check by dump and die `dd(Auth::id)` it will give null.

And about validation.
i guess you forget to place `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">` and also check you having the same name in input field which is in the validator.

Comment: I have changed my code to this but it is not inserting any data in my db even though I am getting redirected to the home page without any error??

Comment: @MonisHussain is user created?

Comment: I am building a registration page where user has to register himself and his data will be inserted into db but it is not working..I want to paste my code but don't know how to do it??